# Missing solutions on projective curve over field?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, modular-arithmetic, finite-fields

I have the polynomial $F(x, y, z)= x^2 + y^2 + z^2$.
I'm defining the projective curve $\overline{C}$ as $F(x, y, z) = 0$.

I'm trying to find the points in $\overline{C}(F_3)$, where $F_3$ is the same thing as $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$.

Apparently, the solutions are: (1: 1: 1), (1 : 1: 2), (1: 2: 1), and (1: 2: 2).

These solutions all make sense. However, I'm confused as to why other permutations of x/y/z like:

- (2, 1, 1)
- (2, 1, 2)
- (2, 2, 1)

are also not valid solutions

Comment: Because we are working projectively (with homogeneous coordinates). $(2:1:1) = (1:2:2)$.

Comment: @MorganRodgers Isn't $(2: 1: 1)$ translated to the XY-plane equal to $(2, 1)$. And, $(1: 2: 2)$ translated to the real plane is $(\frac{1}{2}, 1)$.

What I'm saying is, I know in projective-land (don't know precise term) the coordinate $(1: 1: 1)$ is equal to $(2: 2: 2)$ or $(9: 9: 9)$, but here the ratios are different (the coordinates are not homothetic).

Comment: @MorganRodgers For example, Wikipedia says "The point represented by a given set of homogeneous coordinates is unchanged if the coordinates are multiplied by a common factor." but $(1: 2: 2)$ is not equal to $(2: 1: 1)$ times some common factor.

Comment: What Morgan Rodgers said. An occasionally useful trick to avoid overcounting projective points is that the homogeneous coordinates become unique, if you normalize the first (or the last) non-zero coordinate to $1$. This seems to be the method used in your source.